# how to put an executable file under a folder?

Tags: makefile

My original directory structure is:

> include/ ( const.h , map_reduce.h )
>
> src/ ( main.c , map_reduce.c )
>
> Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
BINS = bin_mapreduce

all: $(BINS)

bin_mapreduce: bin/mapreduce

bin/mapreduce: mapreduce | bin

mapreduce:
    gcc $(CFLAGS) src/main.c -o bin/$@

bin:
    mkdir $@


clean:
    rm -f bin/mapreduce


clean:
    rm -f bin/mapreduce
```

I want to create a bin folder if there is no one.

Then, compile main.c to executable mapreduce file and put it into bin folder.

However, for bin/$@, if I add bin/ before $@, it shows a error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file bin/mapreduce: No such file or
>   directory
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Makefile:19: recipe for target 'mapreduce' failed
>
> make: *** [mapreduce] Error 1

If do it without bin/, just :

```
 gcc $(CFLAGS) src/main.c -o $@
```

If creates a mapreduce file outside the bin folder, the bin folder is created.

How can I put mapreduce file in the bin folder?

Comment: You could cd into bin/ in the mapreduce target, and thus compile your sources inside the bin/ directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bin/mapreduce: mapreduce | bin
```

That rule is not correct. You need `bin` to be created before `mapreduce` is run. But that rule does not achieve that sequencing. Here are some options:

- Put the order only prerequisite on the `mapreduce` target:

  ```
  mapreduce: | bin
  ```
- Put the order only prerequisite on a `$(BINS)` target:

  ```
  $(BINS) : | bin
  ```